# Do post-IPO 'insider' stock lockup periods still apply if you separate from the company

Tags: united-states, stocks, ipo

Typically employees and other 'insiders' are subject to a lockup period after an initial public offering, along with blackout periods at certain points throughout the year to curb insider trading.  Would ending employment with such an organization remove the restrictions on selling during said periods?

Comment: What country. Please edit the question and add country tag. The answer would depend on 1. Regulations in place. 2. Agreement with the company. There are quite a few clauses that canbe/are applicable even after termination of employment. It depends on what you have signed.

Comment: In the US.  Nothing relevant to this circumstance is included in the option agreement.

Comment: do you still have access to the insider information?

Comment: This question is absolutely a figurative example, but I would presume that ongoing access to such information would end, given that the subject no longer has information provided by former associates at the organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few regulations on "Insider Trading". Blackouts are one of the means companies adopt to comply with "Insider Trading" regulations, mandating employees to refrain from selling/buying during the notified period.

Once you leave the employment:

- The "Insider Trading" is still applicable to you as individual. i.e. if it can be established that you had more information than available in public domain before you traded in the stock,
- The company may [or may not] impose additional blackout periods depending on your agreement with the company, for a period of time. In your case it looks like its' not there.

So unless there is an urgent need for you to sell/buy the options, wait for some time and then indulge in trade.